# open ruby gem documentation from the command line

Tags: ruby, rubygems, documentation

When I install ruby gems, both **rdoc** and **ri** versions of documentation are installed.  The files get buried deep in my **rbenv** directory, and there seems to be no simple way to access them-- I have to open the index file by manually navigating to the directory.  Is there some simple `gem XXXX GEMNAME` command that opens the documentation in the default browser? I can't find one listed in the output of `gem help commands`. If there is no such command, what is a good method for quickly accessing gem docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref. http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#viewing-documentation

You can use `ri [options] [names]` command, e.g. `ri RBTree`. `ri --help` for more info.

or `gem server` command, where you can access the docs at localhost:8808

Answer (score 0):

There used to be [OpenGem](https://github.com/brockgr/open_gem) but it appears to have fallen into disrepair.

You could use the `gem server` command to start a local documentation server.